# How to clone a Github Gist via SSH protocol?

Tags: git, github, gist

Github really seems to want us to use the HTTPS protocol to use Gists, for example, they only list the HTTPS url on a Gist page - e.g. https://gist.github.com/donatello/5834862

Is it possible to clone a Gist using SSH protocol?

Comment: what's wrong with https? ;)

Comment: It seems to be require me to specify the username and password on the command line each time I use the protocol. It works fine with SSH for me (no need to specify username/password every time)

Comment: Also, HTTPS auth gets trickier if you enable 2-factor auth.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

```
git clone git@github.com:5834862.git
```

Just replace with your own Gist ID of course.

Comment: that's SSH, not git://

Comment: You are more than likely going to want also pass the gist name on the command line: git clone git@github.com:5834862.git gist_name

Comment: you edited your question to fit your answer? :D classic!
Now, what is the question for the answer 42? ;)

Comment: I'm behind a firewall, and the trick to talk SSH over port 443 (SSL) doesn't seem to work with gist.github.com the way it does with ssh.github.com.

Comment: clones successfully but unable to push :|

Comment: In 2023, we have the official GitHub CLI. Is it possible to use SSH protocol in `gh gist clone` command?

Answer (score 28):

The dropdown on gist pages now has Embed/Share/Clone HTTPS/Clone SSH options (but the SSH option is only shown when you're **logged in**):
[image: gist dropdown]
which show the non-obvious trick is **omitting the user name**:

- Clone HTTPS:
  `https://gist.github.com/b6f4a53fac485f75afb9150d03efb2f6.git`
  Works for me with or without `.git`, and with or without the username:
  `https://gist.github.com/cben/b6f4a53fac485f75afb9150d03efb2f6`
  (as usual on github, the canonical browsing URL works for git too)
- Clone SSH:
  `git@gist.github.com:b6f4a53fac485f75afb9150d03efb2f6.git`
  AKA
  **`ssh://git@gist.github.com/b6f4a53fac485f75afb9150d03efb2f6.git`**
  Works for me with or without `.git`, but doesn't work with username.

---

I enabled github 2FA which makes HTTPS painful so I always want SSH;
the following `~/.gitconfig` does the translation for all gists on push:

```
[url "ssh://git@gist.github.com/"]
    # In case I just copy-pasted with username:
    # [only works for my (cben) gists, but those are the ones I can push]
    pushInsteadOf = https://gist.github.com/cben/
    # For gists cloned with official no-username URL:
    pushInsteadOf = https://gist.github.com/
```

And for regular (non-gist) repos:

```
[url "ssh://git@github.com/"]
    pushInsteadOf = https://github.com/
[url "ssh://git@bitbucket.org/"]
    pushInsteadOf = https://bitbucket.org/
[url "ssh://git@gitlab.com/"]
    pushInsteadOf = https://gitlab.com/
```

P.S. a handy easy way to debug `insteadOf` and `pushInsteadOf` configs is run `git remote -v`, it shows the effective URLs fetch/push will use.

Comment: I found I had to remove `gist.` from the SSH URI to get `git clone` to succeed. If I left `gist.github.com` instead of using `github.com`, the command just hung.

Comment: As of Sep 2020, the "Embed/Share/Clone..." menu is gone.

Comment: Weird, I still see it, both logged in and not.

Comment: The _menu_ is visible but the option/URLs for SSH is not displayed unless you're logged in. Only displays these options/tabs to anonymous users: HTTPS, GitHub CLI, Open with GH Desktop, Download zip.

Comment: Apparently was removed. The menu is not showing for me

Comment: @sehe see my previous options — it's there but SSH is only shown when you're logged in.  (In any case `git clone` won't care if you're logged in the browser, only that your SSH keys are configured.)

Comment: @BeniCherniavsky-Paskin It is not visible. I checked on my own gist and I am logged in. I see two buttons: Save using Github Desktop and Download as zip.

Comment: I see that now, in a narrow window the whole dropdown disappears.  Try maximizing the browser window / reducing font size?

Comment: @BeniCherniavsky-Paskin Reducing font size did it! Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use#ssh-readwrite---gitgithubspanspancom

git@..... is the ssh protocol

when you copy the clone url for a gist it shows you the https clone url

`https://gist.github.com/5834862.git`

change `https://` to `git@` and `/****.git` to `:****.git`

so in this case

`git clone git@gist.github.com:5834862.git`

Answer (score 2):

If you want, you could grab [this](https://gist.github.com/sankalp-khare/11356560) script and put it somewhere in your `$PATH`. Once that is done, you can do the following:

1. Clone any gist from `gist.github.com` using `HTTPS` (or if you have an already cloned gist, just proceed to the next step)
2. Anywhere in the gist's git directory tree, run the command

```sh
git-change-url --to-ssh
```

Now, provided that your public key is uploaded to your github account (it should be listed [here](https://github.com/settings/ssh)) you should be able to work with the gist via `SSH`, without having to enter your github credentials.

Much less error-prone than editing git config files by hand.

Ps: If you find any bugs in the script, or have any additions to make, feel free to fork :D

Comment: Not exactly what the op asked for, but still useful! I didn't want to clone my existing repository so this solution worked for me. I would add `nano $(git rev-parse --git-dir)/config` as an alternative to directly modify the entries manually. So the answer will be more self contained ;). Otherwise you first have to download a script and check if it might do harm to your system and s.o.

Answer (score 2):

Change `https://` to `ssh://git@` should do the trick, that is, change

```
https://gist.github.com/donatello/5834862
```

to

```
ssh://git@gist.github.com/donatello/5834862
```

so `git clone ssh://git@gist.github.com/...` should clone the project (if you have already added SSH key on Github)

In my personal opinion, the [official document](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use#ssh-readwrite---gitgithubspanspancom) is unclear about SSH.

Comment: Currently https works both with and without username but SSH only without username e.g. `ssh://git@gist.github.com/5834862`.

Answer (score 1):

In order for it to work, one gotta remove the username from the path, leaving only the hash / numbers alone.

Answer (score 0):

SSH and HTTPS links to clone the gist can be copied directly through GitHub's interface, as shown by **Beni Cherniavsky-Paskin**'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40743558/18569952)

However the gist is going to be put in a git directory with that ugly hash as name.

This can be avoided by specifying a directory name when cloning:

```bash
git clone git@gist.github.com:9e7f15ae79acd6b60519ef094f669b26.git speedtest-loop
```

Answer (score -1):

It is possible, Try this:

```
git clone git@YOURSSHHOST:YOURGISTIDHERE.git
```