# Github Gist via SSH protocol doesn't work

Tags: github, ssh, gist

I'm using two-factor auth and that's why HTTPS isn't convenient way to work with GitHub repos and gists.

I have correct *config* and *github_pr_key* files in my *~/.ssh* directory.

I'm able to clone all my personal and public repos.

But I can't clone via SSH any of my private or public gists, I have this error:

```
~/Desktop >> git clone git@gist.github.com:d1b8041051e62aa34f337b3dabc77d9a.git                                                                                                                                
Cloning into 'd1b8041051e62aa34f337b3dabc77d9a'...
The authenticity of host 'gist.github.com (192.30.253.118)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl22E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'gist.github.com,192.30.253.118' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

How it can be fixed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check first the reasons mentioned in "[Error: Permission denied (publickey)](https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey/)".
Double-check the output of `ssh -Tv git@github.com`, to confirm your public key is registered on your GitHub account.

But don't forget that you can still [use https with 2FA](https://help.github.com/articles/providing-your-2fa-authentication-code/#when-youll-be-asked-for-a-personal-access-token-as-a-password).
[Create a PAT (Personnal Access Token)](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line/), and use it as password.
That should be enough to allow you to clone anything, including your private Gists.

Finally, try to clone through ssh with `git@github.com`, not `git@gist.github.com` (as seen [in 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18019143/6309), even though `git@gist.github.com` should work):

```
git clone git@github.com:d1b8041051e62aa34f337b3dabc77d9a.git <=== does work 
NOT
git clone git@gist.github.com:d1b8041051e62aa34f337b3dabc77d9a.git
```

Just for testing, try also:

```
git clone ssh://git@gist.github.com/d1b8041051e62aa34f337b3dabc77d9a.git
```

(this time with `git@gist.github.com`)

---

As noted by [Jacktose](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144854/jacktose) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44267593/github-gist-via-ssh-protocol-doesnt-work/44272502?noredirect=1#comment131289426_44272502):

> If `ssh -Tv git@github.com` works, try `ssh -Tv git@gist.github.com` and compare.
>
> In my case, the latter was using the wrong public key because `.ssh/config` specified `IdentityFile` under `Host github.com`.
> I changed that to `Host github.com *.github.com` and problems solved.

Comment: I've executed ssh -Tv git@github.com and it seems to be fine: http://prntscr.com/fez2gn

Comment: @КагарлицкийДмитрий It does indeed... Can you clone one your your private repo (repo, not gist) with ssh? Regarding gist, would at least an https clone work (with a token as password)?

Comment: I can clone private repos via SSH and HTTPS;and I can clone Gists via HTTPS, but not via SSH

Comment: thanks, the correct one is git clone git@github.com:d1b8041051e62aa34f337b3dabc77d9a.git

Comment: If `ssh -Tv git@github.com` works, try `ssh -Tv git@gist.github.com` and compare. In my case, the latter was using the wrong public key because .ssh/config specified `IdentityFile` under `Host github.com`. I changed that to `Host github.com *.github.com` and problems solved.

Comment: @Jacktose Thank you for the feedback. Good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.